# How to disable auto generation routing-module in Ionic CLI 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I'm kinda new on Ionic and I'm currently using **Ionic CLI 5.4.15** and **@ionic/angular 4.11.10**.

When I want to generate **new page**, each page is now automatically creating an associated **routing-module.ts** and I was wondering if it was possible to disable this new functionnality.

Exemple :

```
C:\Users\Stagiaire\wIonic\Mango>ionic generate
? What would you like to generate? page
? Name/path of page: home
> ng.cmd generate page home
CREATE src/app/home/home-routing.module.ts (339 bytes)
CREATE src/app/home/home.module.ts (458 bytes)
CREATE src/app/home/home.page.html (123 bytes)
CREATE src/app/home/home.page.spec.ts (633 bytes)
CREATE src/app/home/home.page.ts (248 bytes)
CREATE src/app/home/home.page.scss (0 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app-routing.module.ts (526 bytes)
[OK] Generated page!
```

As you can see the **home-routing.module.ts** is auto generated and I would like to disable this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is your problem if you keep it?

Comment: Well I don't need a routing-module on every pages and If I create 20 pages It's annoying to delete the file and the link auto created in the page module aswell.

Comment: In prev ionic version , you could write in the console --no-module to remove the module from creation, but for routing till now there is no such thing, you should make the proccess manually.